# Checking if a value is equal to another value and if that is true go back to another value

Tags: java, encryption, ascii

Hi everyone quick java question,

I am trying to use the Ascii table to encrypt and decrypt messages which will eventually be typed by the user.

[Ascii Table](http://www.asciitable.com/)

[I have the base encryption code here](https://repl.it/join/ofnerfmk-terminator69851)

Once the code gets to z or Z the shift displays { and [ respectively while I am trying to get the code to loop back to a and A respectively

z --> a not {
Z --> A not [

Please ask if you need any clarification since I'm not very sure about my wording

Comment: hi, perhaps check if the value is 90 (`Z`) or 122 (`z`) and then, instead of incrementing it, reassign the value to 65 (`A`) or 97 (`a`) respectively.

Comment: Its a simple for loop with if else. And do not put the link code here. Put the exact problematic precise piece of code where you are having issues. Welcome to SO.

Comment: Link with code doesn't work. No minimum working example included. Avoid using external links as they go stale over time.

Answer (score 0):

The cipher you are programming is the caesar cipher.

Here is a an implementation of it I coded a while ago:

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(caesar("hello", 1));
    }

    public static String caesar(String text, int offset) {

        String output = "";
        char outputchar;

        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            if (isLetter(text.charAt(i))) {
                outputchar = (char) (text.charAt(i) + offset);

                if (Character.isUpperCase(text.charAt(i))) {
                    if ((!isLetter(outputchar)) || (Character.isLowerCase(outputchar))) {
                        outputchar = (char) (outputchar - 26);
                    }
                } else {
                    if ((!isLetter(outputchar)) || (Character.isUpperCase(outputchar))) {
                        outputchar = (char) (outputchar - 26);
                    }
                }
                output += outputchar;
            } else {
                output += text.charAt(i);
            }
        }
        return output;
    }


    public static boolean isLetter(char letter) {
        return ((letter >= 97) && (letter <= 122) || (letter >= 65) && (letter <= 90));
    }
}
```

It handles the problem you posted by checking whether the `char` is in range of where it belongs, including case correction.